# Prove -1 Transformation (A binomial identity):$\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

Prove the following binomial identity :

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q
\end{align*}
$$
I played with $\binom{-p}{q}$ for a while but found nothing .

Comment: How do you define $\binom{p}{q}$? [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html), this appears to basically be the definition of binomial coefficients when extended to negative numbers.

Comment: $$\frac{p!}{q!(p-q)!}$$

Comment: How do you define $p!$ for $p$ negative?

Comment: Well I've heard about gamma function but not sufficiently. And I think we can avoid all troubles of negative factorial by considering $C(-p,q)=\frac{P(-p,q)}{P(q,q)}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for real $\alpha$ and positive integer $q$, $\alpha\choose q$ is defined by:
$${\alpha\choose q}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\cdots(\alpha-(q-1))}{q!}.$$
So:
$${-p\choose q}= \frac{(-p)(-p-1)(-p-2)\cdots(-p-(q-1))}{q!}=
(-1)^q\cdot\frac{p(p+1)(p+2)\cdots (p+(q-1))}{q!}=\\ =(-1)^q\cdot\frac{(p+q-1)!}{q!(p-1)!}=
(-1)^q{p+q-1\choose q}.$$